# jQuery CSS change reverting back to original!

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, master-pages

I have setup some tabbed navigation on my ASP.NET Masterpage.  It is pretty basic:

```
    <div id="nav_tabs">
        <div id="home" class="tab selected_tab "><a href="Default.aspx" onclick="tabSwitch('home');">Home</a></div>
        <div id="products" class="tab other_tab "><a href="ProductList.aspx" onclick="tabSwitch('products');">Products</a></div>
        <div id="demos" class="tab other_tab "><a href="Demos.aspx" onclick="tabSwitch('demos');">Demos</a></div>
    </div>
```

And I use the following jQuery to set the current tab:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
      function tabSwitch(tab) {
          $('.tab').css("background-image", "url('/Images/other_Tab.png')");
          $("#" + tab).css("background-image", "url('/Images/Active_Tab.png')");
      }
  </script>
```

For some reason when I click on one of the tabs, the changes are briefly shown, but then they revert back to their original state.  Is this a side effect of the MasterPage?  Am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that after jQuery changes css page reload occurs. And of course elements return to their original state.

Master page is just a convenient way to construct pages, it's not a frameset. So you need to either implement your style changes on the server side or persist your changes somehow (for example save # of tab in a cookie and update css on every reload based on that cookie). I think in your case server side method is better.

Comment: By page reload do you mean a postback?

Comment: Yes. Page is resent, DOM tree is re-created by browser and all changes to DOM made by client script are lost. So you should do it on server side (for instance, checking for `Request.Path` in master page and adjusting image url accordingly). Or you can do it on the client side, in `$(document).ready`, for example to ensure that state is restored on each page reload. (You can for example check which tab contains a link to the current page and change image for it)

Comment: BTW clicking on a link in nav_tabs won't cause "Postback". `IsPostback` will be false...

Comment: To further expand on the above. Clicking tab link will navigate you to the new web page, new URL etc so no "Postback"occurs. You are now on a new page so no state is automatically retained

Comment: Thanks Jon, that makes more sense.